# Fedora 30 MATE Apps Search

Tags: fedora, mate-desktop

I just switched to the *MATE* environment on my Fedora 30 (from Gnome) and I am very surprised of how much different it is compared to Mint MATE.
In Mint MATE I can open the **Main Menu** and start typing and it's searching through the installed apps from which I can choose one. How can I do this with *Fedora MATE*?

Is there a way to search through the installed apps and **Main Menu** items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install mate-menu

```
yum install mate-menu
```

After that add "MATE menu" to panel. In MATE menu you can search menu item.